# Is there anyone built a successful rosserial-android demo based on Adam Stambler APIs in Android Studio?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following Adam Stambler APIs to built my demo of rosserial-android in Android Studio, but here comes a lots of mistakes in classes. I'm wonder maybe there're some configuration missing (even mistakes), or the APIs is too old to follow? I configured my project settings with the guiding: http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment.

I'm new to ros and rosserial android. Help, guys! Any suggestions would welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257965/is-there-anyone-built-a-successful-rosserial-android-demo-based-on-adam-stambler-apis-in-android-studio?/) by [Zorcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29838/zorcs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the official API is too old to follow, and fortunately there's come a more better way in Android to transport messages with the good support of android_core in rosjava, so it's time that you should quit this way to make a try in rosjava. And fortunately there's also a good way to make it work that just transport messages in your application without a support of the ros-environment, help this can help the beginners like me to build theirs applications. Good luck! Myself's question for build your first [ros-android pubsub demo](http://answers.ros.org/question/258980/problems-to-set-buildgradle-files-in-my-demo-that-built-based-on-official-example-android_tutorial_pubsub/) maybe can help you!

---

Originally posted by [Zorcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29838/zorcs/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0